Replacing 28x28 images in MNIST dataset
I'm working on something where I'm experimenting with the fashion_mnist dataset (I'm following the Autoencoder tutorial on TensorFlow). I would like to replace the 28x28 images with something of my own. I have a csv file with random numbers, and I would like to see the response of the autoencoder.
path = open("data.csv")
with np.load(path) as p:
    x_train, y_train = p['x_train'], p['y_train']
    x_test, y_test = p['x_test'], p['y_test']

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

class Autoencoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim, shape):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.shape = shape

        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Flatten(),
            layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'),
        ])
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(tf.math.reduce_prod(shape).numpy(), activation='sigmoid'),
            layers.Reshape(shape)
        ])

    def call(self, x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return decoded


autoencoder = Autoencoder(64, x_test.shape[1:])

I'm confused about the dimensions of the original dataset. How would I structure my csv file for the same code to work (I've filled it with random numbers using numpy)?
I'm assuming that the autoencoder would be highly inefficient, because it's learning randomness and trying to rebuild it. Nevertheless, I would still like this to run without a dimension error.
